# Invalid column name? c# sql

Tags: c#, sql

Why isnt this working? it says invalid column name when i try to remove something after i added it

```
    private void btnRemoveCommand_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        connection.Open();         

        for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.SelectedItems.Count; i++)
        {
            var sql = "DELETE FROM Commands WHERE commandName = " + listBox1.SelectedItems[i] + "";

            listBox1.Items.Remove(listBox1.SelectedItems[i]);               
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        connection.Close();
    }
```

this is the event that handles the addCommand to the database

```
private void btnAddCommand_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var sql = "INSERT INTO Commands(commandName, pathToCommand) VALUES(@commandName, @pathToCommand)";
                using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    connection.Open();

                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);

                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@commandName", tbxCommand.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pathToCommand", tbxPathToCommand.Text);

                    int affectedRows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
var sql = "DELETE FROM Commands WHERE commandName = " + listBox1.SelectedItems[i] + "";
```

to

```
var sql = "DELETE FROM Commands WHERE commandName = '" + listBox1.SelectedItems[i] + "'";
```

Comment: Wow! thanks for the help! really appriciated : ), worked flawlessly

Comment: I'll give you the answer on this post whenever i can

Comment: Even better (and then I mean MUCH better) would be to use **`SqlParameter`**, that way you never have to worry about (a) enclosing quotes, (b) embedded quotes that need escaping, (c) SQL injection. E.g. see http://csharp-station.com/Tutorial/AdoDotNet/Lesson06. You even used in the second code block, should also use it in the first!

Answer (score 1):

First thing is first, [always always, always use parameterised queries. No exceptions. Ever.](https://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/)

Next, use `using` blocks for objects that implement iDisposable, to ensure your unmanaged resources are properly cleaned up.

Finally, when removing items from the a collection you should to iterate in reverse to ensure you don't skip over any items:

```
private void btnRemoveCommand_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = listBox1.SelectedItems.Count; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        using (var command = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM Commands WHERE commandName = @Command;", connection))
        {   
            connection.Open();
            //Add parameter with Add method - you may need to address the data type
            command.Parameters.Add("@Command", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = listBox1.SelectedItems[i];
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        listBox1.Items.Remove(listBox1.SelectedItems[i]);   
    }
}
```

This is still not ideal, because if you have 1000 items, you are executing 1000 queries. My preferred way of doing this is with [table valued parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/table-valued-parameters). The first step would be to create a table type in the database. I tend to use generic naming for ease of reuse:

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.ListOfString AS TABLE (Value NVARCHAR(MAX));
```

Then you can pass this type to your query to delete the records

```
private void btnRemoveCommand_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var table = new DataTable();
    table.Columns.Add("Value", typeof(string));
    for (int i = listBox1.SelectedItems.Count; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        table.Rows.Add(new []{listBox1.SelectedItems[i]});
        listBox1.Items.Remove(listBox1.SelectedItems[i]);   
    }
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (var command = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM Commands WHERE commandName IN (SELECT Value FROM @Commands);", connection)
    {   
        connection.Open();
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Commands", SqlDbType.Structured) { Value = table, TypeName = "dbo.ListOfInt" });
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Now you send a single command to the database, which is more efficient than sending multiple commands.

Comment: I see , so you are basicly creating a datatable to store all of it in there and send that as a query instead of sending a query for each and every single commandName pretty much? Ye i will be using using disposables! just did this quicky just to get it working, have disposable in some other event handlers , will switch it over^^

Comment: Yes, exactly. If you are deleting a small number of items you will most likely find there is little or no difference, but with a lot of items you should see an increase in performance with just issuing a single query.

Comment: oh oki got it! What do you mean? my database table is called " Commands " thats the table im refering to in the sql query ? ^^

Comment: @wille480 There was another comment that has since been deleted asking if the table will be removed after the operation has finished. I have now removed my response to this too to avoid any further confusion.

Comment: Is this applicable to the other DML commands like insert and update?

Comment: @TraxX If you mean can you use table valued parameters for these commands then yes.

Comment: Sorry for this question too but where can i see the created type in SSMS? I can't find it in my tables folder.

Comment: In object explorer under `{Database} > Programmability > Types > User-Defined Table Types`

Comment: Thank you so much. Btw, I'm that guy who asked about "if the table will be removed after the operation finished" but I think I just need to try to see the results. Thank you again.